# resample or interpolate a unevenly spaced path

Tags: matlab, interpolation, resampling

Let's say I have a path made of 3D points, where the distance between consecutive points is not constant.

How do I resample it such that distance between consecutive points becomes constant?

I tried to look into `interp1` but I don't know original query points of a hypotetically parametrized curve x(t),y(t),z(t).

Example path:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [**`interparc`**](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34874-interparc) from the *Matlab File Exchange*. In the following example, this function calculates 100 equally spaced points of the original curve. By default a spline-interpolation is used and gives a smooth curve. By defining an optional parameter, we can change this behaviour. Use `'linear'` for a linear approximation (most efficient).

*Here is the code:*

```
% define some original points
A = [0.132488479262673 0.427113702623907;0.160138248847926 0.462099125364431;0.197004608294931 0.532069970845481;0.236175115207373 0.634110787172012;0.263824884792627 0.677842565597668;0.284562211981567 0.709912536443149;0.307603686635945 0.744897959183673;0.339861751152074 0.785714285714286;0.376728110599078 0.806122448979592;0.40668202764977 0.814868804664723;0.452764976958525 0.817784256559767;0.498847926267281 0.82069970845481;0.521889400921659 0.82069970845481;0.542626728110599 0.82069970845481;0.561059907834101 0.817784256559767;0.579493087557604 0.806122448979592;0.639400921658986 0.759475218658892;0.669354838709677 0.721574344023324;0.713133640552995 0.654518950437318;0.752304147465438 0.581632653061224;0.784562211981567 0.485422740524781;0.793778801843318 0.412536443148688;0.784562211981567 0.316326530612245;0.773041474654378 0.284256559766764;0.754608294930876 0.260932944606414;0.722350230414747 0.231778425655977;0.660138248847926 0.214285714285714;0.567972350230415 0.188046647230321];

% plot original
figure
plot(A(:,1),A(:,2),'*-')

% interpolate
B = interparc(100,A(:,1),A(:,2));             % spline
%B = interparc(100,A(:,1),A(:,2),'linear');   % linear

% plot interpolated
figure
plot(B(:,1),B(:,2),'*-')
```

*This is the result:*
[image: result1_1]
[image: result1_2]

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I just want to point out that using the default interpolation method (spline), always gives me the error at chckxy (line 51) "The data sites should be distinct.". However linear interpolation is more than fine for me.